# SSRS filter templates

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I created a report with several filters , in which users can set integer values.

Now I want to create an additional parameter, called "method" which will be a two options drop down list and will set all the other values.

For example: when first option is chosen , parameter A gets 0.1 , B - 0.2 , C - 0.3. An when second option is chosen , A gets 1 , B - 2 and C - 3

("method" is kind of a filters templates collection)

In addition , I still need to allow the users to change any of this values if they want.

These are not cascading filters , and have nothing to do with sql queries , thus I can't find a solution.

I tried to write the following expression in one of the parameters but with no success:

```
=IIF(Parameters!method.Value=1,0.3,1)
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to add a drop down that will act as a Stored Defaults or like a favorites. This is easy enough however, when you say you want the user to be able to change values, would it be OK if they first set the Default to ALL?

Comment: Indeed you got it right.  I would prefer that the default would set the values of the first option since it will be used most. Thank you.